# Javascript operator precedence question: i = i— + ++i

Tags: javascript, operator-precedence

Please consider this snippet of code:

```
var i = 1;
i = i-- + ++i;
```

My understanding of the order in which the operators & operands are processed  is as follows:

1. i is incremented by 1 (pre-fix increment)
2. i is added to i( addition )
3. i is decremented by 1(post-fix decrement)
4. The value of the right hand side is assigned to i (assignment operation)

If my understanding is correct, i should end up having a value of 3. However, I printed out the result using some online javascript interpreter, and the end value of i is 2.

Where did I get wrong?

Comment: You ignored #3 when you calculated the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var i = 1;
i = i-- + ++i;
```

this is how the compiler will go about working through this code

1. create a variable called i
2. set the value of i to 1
3. (rhs first element) take value of i (1) decrement value (i is now 0)
4. (rhs second element) increment value of i (i is now 1)
5. set the value of i to rhs (2)

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript always evaluates subexpressions in a left-to-right order, and then applies the operator:

```
// parentheses added for clarity
i = (i--) + (++i); // i = 1

i =   1   + (++i); // i = 0 after i--

i =   1   +   1  ; // i = 1 after ++i

i =       2      ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Understanding the logic with precedence values:

```
var i = 1;
i = i-- + ++i;

prefix increment(++i) precedence  = 17
postfix decrement(i--) precedence = 16

addition(+) precedence = 14

i = 1 + 1
i = 2
```

More precedence related info can be found in,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence